# Show to visualize SMART data of the HDDs and SSDs on a Megaraid 9361 8i controller

Tags: windows, raid, smart, megaraid

Is there a way to see the SMART disk data of my drives when using a Megaraid 9361 i8?

The Megaraid storage controller doesn't seam to have such a feature.

Would be nice to see how much data was written to some SSDs.

`storcli64 /c0/e252/s5 show smart` just show some raw hey data. I can't find any interpretation for the data.

Answer (score 0):

To get SMART data behind Broadcom MegaRAID controllers:

- Query the MegaRAID controller 0 for the DID list for the drives:

  ```
    storcli /c0 /eall /sall show
  ```
- Run `lsblk -l` to get your drive letter
- With the above information use `smartctl` to query the drives.
  Change the DID for each drive, and in a RAID the device does not change:

  ```
    smartctl —a —d megaraid,43 /dev/sdb
    smartctl —a —d megaraid,8l /dev/sdb
    smartctl —a —d megaraid,82 /dev/sdb
  ```

The above is based on the article
[Getting SMART data behind Broadcom MegaRAID controllers](https://support.siliconmechanics.com/portal/en/kb/articles/getting-smart-data-behind-broadcom-megaraid-controllers),
where you may find more information and screenshots.

Comment: Id didn't wrote it explicitly but I need it for Windows.

Comment: For Windows try [smartmontools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/). See [tutorial](https://www.ionos.com/help/server-cloud-infrastructure/server-administration-dedicated-servers/diagnose-and-replace-a-defective-hard-drive-windows-dedicated-server-with-software-raid/). Also see [gsmartcontrol](https://github.com/ashaduri/gsmartcontrol).